# Querying current seat utilization for Box Org

Tags: box-api

Is there an efficient way to obtain the number of seats utilized in your org?  There's the "Get Enterprise Users" call, but it appears to return all your users in paginated form.  Sounds like an expensive way to just get a current user count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [paginated result](https://developer.box.com/v2.0/reference#pagination-1) returned by [Get Enterprise Users](https://developer.box.com/v2.0/reference#get-all-users-in-an-enterprise) includes a `total_count` field that indicates the size of the collection. You can request a small subset of the collection (`offset=0&limit=1`) to speed up the request.

Comment: Awesome.  That worked great.  I ended up extending the Box Python SDK's client class to include a method to return the user count in this way.